# Please delete my account

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have tried several times to post reasonable questions concerning politics, and always gotten a bad response...i.e. off-topic, POB, etc

For a site in beta, one would think there could be more latitude; however, here user-moderation  seems to be limiting without actually defining the scope of the site.

In lieu of that, we have a lot opinionated comments from users  which are not supported by their past answers or comments. Instead..this looks like an old-boy's club, a mob fighting for the right to claim the diamond next to their name.

I resigned from Literature.SE for a similar reason.

I am not new to SE; point in fact I probably have more flair than a lot of people posting here.

Lemme out.

Answer (score 17):

If you wish your account removed, please use the "Delete Profile" option on your user profile:

[image]

Please note that:

> User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.

You may find more information in the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Comment: You seem eager to get rid of me. I will think about it on my pillow.

Comment: If that was true, I'd delete your account myself @Cascabel...

Comment: Erm..that is not a really good comment. Just goes to what I was saying. I see this has been an issue in the past:https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/please-stop-it-with-the-serial-downvoting

Comment: "You seem eager to get rid of me" isn't that great of a comment either @Cascabel. All I did here is provide you with the information you asked for. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Only an observation On other sites there might be some kind of self-reflection, and possible explanation of actual site standards, as a courtesy. A Mod might look at the user's bio see that although  no newbie, might not be aware of the peculiarities and culture  of the site, as all seem to have?     ...users could leave off playing politics. The Help Page could be more forthcoming. Need I go on?

Comment: If you have specific suggestions about the site's standards, culture and help articles please post them as separate Meta discussions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. You asked for advice on deleting your account. yannis gave you the advice you asked for. And somehow this means he's "eager to get rid of you"? What were you expecting him to do, grovel on his knees and beg you to stay? Ignore your request entirely?

Comment: All you had to say was "Sorry to see you go but" or "I hope you will reconsider but" at the start of the answer.

Answer (score -8):

Please consider sticking around a while longer, *Politics.SE* needs more dissidents.

Yes, there do seem to be obliviously partisan and adversarial Knights of the *Status Quo* here that selectively pounce upon minor technicalities.  But if it wasn't those guys, it'd probably be somebody else.

A mere 750 rep. points allows one to see the up/down vote counts which helps put the drama in perspective.  A good post might have `-1` votes, but underneath the vote counts might be `+10/-11`.